# How do I create a FeedItem post with an @collaborationgroup

Tags: apex, chatter-feed

I've created a feed item post without issue but setting the @ in the body text does not work. How do I accomplish this

Happening on a case object

```
{
  FeedItem fi = new FeedItem();
  fi.parentid = c.id;
  fi.type = 'AdvancedTextPost'; // I've tried a few variations here
  fi.visibility = 'AllUsers';
  fi.body = '@Level-1-Updates Level 1 Case DETECTED for: ' + c.account.name;
  lfi.add(fi);          
}
insert lfi;
```

The problem is the feed item is plain text the collaboration group @Level-1-Updates is not getting notified or treated as a collaboration group. It's treating it as plain text

Comment: see [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm) - see  ConnectAPI

Comment: I've looked at it and just like  the feeditem in my example there does not seem to be a way to connect it to both a specific case record id and mention the group. I can do either but I can't find a way to do both

Comment: your OP does straight DML, have you tried ConnectAPI methods instead?

Comment: I did try ConnectAPI and have done some research on Salesforce Doc's about ConnectAPI and I do not see a way to do both. I found a couple examples that when I try it tells me that method was discontinued. Keep looking and cannot find a ConnectAPI method that will do both that has not been deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Persistence paid off. I found another example where they mentioned the old method being deprecated. So ConnectAPI was the answer. Thanks @cropredy

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kFt8IAE

Comment: Would you mind adding that link?